# Windows 7 blue screen upon startup

Tags: windows-7, vga

Blue screen crash upon startup.
Can someone help?

Dell XPS 15
Windows 7 Ultimate, Service pack 1
Here is the debug information:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\112115-25131-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.19045.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`0361d000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03864730
Debug session time: Sat Nov 21 12:43:34.858 2015 (UTC - 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:11.748
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000007E, {ffffffffc0000420, fffff80003c1a2da, fffff88003b9a478, fffff88003b99cd0}

Probably caused by : vga.sys ( vga!InitializeModeTable+157 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000420, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff80003c1a2da, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: fffff88003b9a478, Exception Record Address
Arg4: fffff88003b99cd0, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------


OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'IntcDAud' and 'WUDFRd.sys' overlap

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000420 - An assertion failure has occurred.

FAULTING_IP: 
hal!x86BiosCall+22
fffff800`03c1a2da cd2c            int     2Ch

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff88003b9a478 -- (.exr 0xfffff88003b9a478)
ExceptionAddress: fffff80003c1a2da (hal!x86BiosCall+0x0000000000000022)
   ExceptionCode: c0000420 (Assertion failure)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0
Assertion: *** Concurrent BIOS calls
    This is a BUG in a driver or kernel
    Perform a stack trace to find the culprit
    The BIOS call will be ignored
    Use gh to continue!!


CONTEXT:  fffff88003b99cd0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff88003b99cd0)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000010
rdx=fffff88003b9a720 rsi=fffffa8019649618 rdi=fffff88003b9a798
rip=fffff80003c1a2da rsp=fffff88003b9a6b0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffff78000000008  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000004f00 r12=0000000000000200 r13=fffff8a005ed7a90
r14=fffff8a005ed7990 r15=fffff8a005ed7790
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
hal!x86BiosCall+0x22:
fffff800`03c1a2da cd2c            int     2Ch
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000420 - An assertion failure has occurred.

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8800525e289 to fffff80003c1a2da

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`03b9a6b0 fffff880`0525e289 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!x86BiosCall+0x22
fffff880`03b9a6f0 fffff880`0524c443 : 00000000`00000007 00000000`00000000 fffff880`03b9a848 00000000`000007ff : VIDEOPRT!VpInt10CallBios+0xb1
fffff880`03b9a750 fffff880`05249b16 : fffffa80`19649618 fffffa80`19640000 fffff880`05252000 fffff880`03b9a9c0 : vga!InitializeModeTable+0x157
fffff880`03b9a810 fffff880`0526c25b : 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : vga!VgaInitialize+0x1e
fffff880`03b9a840 fffff880`0526be6e : 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`008c9ce0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : VIDEOPRT!VideoPortLegacyFindAdapter+0x3a3
fffff880`03b9a930 fffff880`052497f9 : fffffa80`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`008c9ce0 : VIDEOPRT!VideoPortInitialize+0x58a
fffff880`03b9a9a0 fffff800`03a367d7 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`69526f49 fffffa80`0e31ff10 : vga!VgaReinitializationCallback+0x79
fffff880`03b9aa60 fffff800`03791ec6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopCallDriverReinitializationRoutines+0x57
fffff880`03b9aa90 fffff800`03792464 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`32706e50 00000000`00000084 : nt!PnpCompleteSystemStartProcess+0x76
fffff880`03b9aad0 fffff800`0369ab69 : fffff800`037922d0 fffff800`0383b201 fffffa80`0d37d600 00000000`00000000 : nt!PnpDeviceActionWorker+0x194
fffff880`03b9ab70 fffff800`0392ab86 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0d37d660 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`0d367970 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x111
fffff880`03b9ac00 fffff800`036820e6 : fffff880`0396d180 fffffa80`0d37d660 fffff880`039780c0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`03b9ac40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`03b9b000 fffff880`03b95000 fffff880`03b99a20 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxStartSystemThread+0x16


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
vga!InitializeModeTable+157
fffff880`0524c443 3bc3            cmp     eax,ebx

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  vga!InitializeModeTable+157

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: vga

IMAGE_NAME:  vga.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc587

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff88003b99cd0 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_vga!InitializeModeTable+157

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_vga!InitializeModeTable+157

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> .cxr 0xfffff88003b99cd0
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000010
rdx=fffff88003b9a720 rsi=fffffa8019649618 rdi=fffff88003b9a798
rip=fffff80003c1a2da rsp=fffff88003b9a6b0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffff78000000008  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000004f00 r12=0000000000000200 r13=fffff8a005ed7a90
r14=fffff8a005ed7990 r15=fffff8a005ed7790
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
hal!x86BiosCall+0x22:
fffff800`03c1a2da cd2c            int     2Ch
```

Comment: It seems to be unhappy with your screen driver.  Are you able to get in in "Safe Mode" ?

Comment: Assertion failure in `vga.sys` (the Windows generic video driver) while making a BIOS interrupt call. Never seen this one before; you may need to update your machine's firmware. Otherwise, the graphics processor or its firmware (VBIOS) might be damaged.

Comment: try updating the bios to latest version.

Comment: Update the graphic card driver.

Answer (score 0):

Reason to blue screen: 
In simple words when bad driver (not compatible with your hardware/os or buggy) loads; it try to overwrite or access to the core os section in the memory and result become blue screen error.

To tackle this problem you have to uninstall driver if you can access the windows in safe mode or if you can't access windows in safe mode then try to restore it to latest restore point

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you who posted your suggestions. The issue is most likely related to a problem with the laptop power button. It has been intermittently not working. I will be shipping my laptop to Dell for repair (to the tune of @ $300.00).
Thanks again.